# Python if statement with a user input (input()) not working (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, menu

I am trying to create a menu here. The menu allows the user to enter options. There is also a validate function to check if the option the user input was valid or not.

```
def menu():
    while True:
        display_menu()
        user_input = validate("Choose Option")
        if user_input == 1:
            pass

        elif user_input == 2:
            exit()


def display_menu():
    print("1) Application")
    print("2) Quit Application")


def validate1(q):
    user_input = input(q)
    if len(user_input) == 0:
        return False

    elif user_input != "1" or user_input != "2":    # Error is likely here
        print("Invalid option, please choose another option")
        return False

    else:
        return user_input
```

When you run this code, you get:

```
1) Application
2) Quit Application
Choose Option
```

However after entering `1`, the validate function thinks the input `1` is invalid and you get:

```
Invalid option, please choose another option
1) Application
2) Quit Application
Choose Option
```

This should not be the case as `1` should be valid. At first I thought that it was an error regarding the type of the variable `user_input` and I have tried to change it (from line 22):

```
elif user_input != 1 or user_input != 2:
```

However the error still persists.

What is the error here?

Comment: why don't you put a print statement before your if-statment: `print(user_input, type(user_input), len(user_input), user_input != "1", user_input != "2", user_input != "1" or user_input != "2")` so you can see what is going on..?

Comment: @thebjorn I just tried. The output was `1 <class 'str'>`. There seems to be no problem.

Comment: If you'd entered the entire print statement, it would have printed more than that (e.g. `1 <class 'str'> 1 False True True`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elif user_input != "1" or user_input != "2":

lets, assume that your user input is "1" then that will make this statement true as
user_input (1) is not equal to (2)

Therefore you need to change that statement to something else like this :

```
def validate(q):
    user_input = input(q)
    if len(user_input) == 0:
        return False

    if user_input == str(1) or user_input == str(2):    # Valid Options
        return user_input
    else:
        print("Invalid option, please choose another option")
        return False
```

Comment: Oh okay. A small mistake on my part, thanks for your help!